# Angular 2 how to match url param value to json object key response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

Is it possible to match a url param value to match the JSON Object key response in Js or Angular 2?

For example `www.mysite.com/sometpath?matchThisVal="/api/matchMeWithJsonObject"` I want to match `/api/matchMeWithJsonObject` with the JSON Object then console log this object to see what other objects there are inside.

JSON Object to match the url param value.

```
someResponse {
 /api/matchMeWithJsonObject {} Object // Match this with the url param value above
}
```

Can someone point me to the right direction if this is even possible?

Comment: you mean to say you have an object with key as url and value as object and you want to get that object for that key ?

Comment: Yeah pretty much, want to get `/api/matchMeWithJsonObject {} Object` based on the url param in my example.

Comment: I had the same requirement and I went with regex. I had multiple urls each with different values so I used regex to match the input with the key.

Comment: Can you show an example? the object has an identifier "string" however I can't use that  as some other objects will have the same identifier. That's why I'm trying to match the path instead.